# Why I can't open JPEG image from binary?

Tags: python, image, parsing, binary, jpeg

I have a python script that parses a MJPEG stream, obtains the first JPEG from the stream, and writes it to a file. The problem is that I can't open this JPEG with any viewer or browser. The parser seems to work right, at least the JPEG binary obtained starts with a SOI (ff d8) and ends with an EOI (ff d9), as it is expected.

```
stream=urllib.urlopen('MY_URL')
myjpg = open('./myjpg', 'w+')
bytes=''
while j == 0:
    bytes+=stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8') #Start Of Image SOI
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9') #End Of Image EOI
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1: #if index found
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2] #JPG from SOI to EOI
        myjpg.write(jpg)
        j = j + 1
```

My final goal is to display the captured image in a  tag from html.

Comment: And what happens when you run this?

Comment: It writes the binary data from the JPEG in my file. It starts with ff d8 and ends with ff d9, I don't understand why I can't open this image.

Comment: Could you give us the URL to allow us to recreate the stream?

Comment: No, I have my IP Cam in a private network, but you can test it with any public IP Cam with a MJPEG stream

Comment: Have you run a JPEG analysis program on it?

Comment: Share a captured image with something like dropbox and I'll tell you if there's a problem with it.

Comment: This is a link to the last jpg obtained. I have just got it and upload to Drive, I have not tried to open it with any program. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4mbOmDEp9b9Vm1wZ05hckc4YU0/view?usp=sharing